# Ошибка при отображении кадра из AForge в PictureBox

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, камера, aforge

Вот обработчик кадра:

```
private void VideoSourceNewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Image a = eventArgs.Frame;
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = a;
    }));           
}
```

После запуска появляется вот такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она возникает только когда я пытаюсь присвоить изображение pictureBox`у. С сохранением в файл проблем нет.

Comment: Попробуйте записать во временный файл, а потом прочитать `Image.FromFile("temp.jpg")`

Comment: Работает, но нашёл более быстрый способ. Сохраняю во временный поток)

Answer (score 1):

Я реализовал такую ситуацию следующим образом: поскольку класс Bitmap наследуется от абстрактного класса Image, действуем так:

```
//
string filename_ ="OurIm";
Bitmap bitmap = image;
bitmap.Save(filename_  + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = 
System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName
(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), filename_  + ".jpeg");
```

При условии что файл лежит в каталоге сборки.

**Примечание.** На самом деле, проблема возникает из-за того, что экземпляр Image уничтожается после завершения обработки события NewFrame. К моменту выполнения BeginInvoke-делегата он будет уже недействителен, поэтому нужно создавать его копию. Но необязательно именно сохранять ее в файл, можно использовать `Image.Clone` для создания копии в памяти.